# C# & WPF - Understanding windows & classes, & passing window as argument in method

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, window

Newbie question! I have "MainWindow" and "EditSettings", which are classes. As far as I can gather, (please correct me if wrong) they are both classes derived from the Window class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

When I actually want to create a window, I create an instance of the derived class, like so:

```
EditSettings winEditSettings = new EditSettings();
```

This means that winEditSettings is an instance of class EditSettings, which is derived from Window.

If I wanted to then write a method which accepts ANY of my windows as an argument, what would I write as the argument? I initially had:

```
    protected void OpenWindowOnce(Window win)
    {
        //This method tells the user whether the window is already open or not
        foreach (Window n in Application.Current.Windows)
            if (n == win)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The window is already open"); 
            }
            else
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("You have not opened that window yet");
                win.Show(); 
            }
```

It seems as though the IF part of the statement is not working - it keeps telling me that the window is not open yet, and then opening a new version of it. I called the method as follows:

```
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditSettings winEditSettings = new EditSettings();
        OpenWindowOnce(winEditSettings);
    }
```

That's all I have in my program so far - I'm just trying to write a method that prevents windows from being opened more than once. Running this code gives me:

"You have not opened that window yet" --> The window "winEditSettings" is opened.

If I press the button again, I get two messages saying "You have not opened that window yet" and it opens another instance of winEditSettings.

*EDIT*

How can I rewrite my OpenWindowOnce method to accept any instance of any window class? I want to be able to pass winEditSettings, or winMainWindow, or winAbout as parameters.

Comment: I believe that my OpenWindowOnce method is not working, because it is trying to pass an instance of Window as an argument, and I'm giving it an instance of EditSettings. Can I rewrite the method so it accepts any of my windows as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass instances to your method, you have to pass the instance of the opened window to see if it is opened.

Otherwise, just try comparing their types:

```
void ShowWindowOnce(Window window)
{
    foreach (Window n in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (typeof(n) == typeof(window)
        {
            // A window with the given type is opened, no need to show another one so return
            return;
        }
    }

    // No open form with that type was open, show it
    window.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the instanced `Window` to your method, so you need to know if the Window is loaded or not.

```
    private void OpenOnce(Window win)
    {
        foreach (Window n in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (n.GetType() == win.GetType())
            {
                if (n.IsLoaded)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The window is already open");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        win.Show();
    }
```